# How to add null values in columns in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

I had a table and need to add one condition in column.

```
Select Age_Flag from table where (Age_Flag <> "AB" or isnotnull(Age_Flag)=False) and Date="2022-17-01";
```

My condition was to exclude only Age_Flag=AB and include all null value.The above query excluding null value and Age_Flag=AB.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for `NULL` values with `IS` in hive also

So your query will be

```
Select Age_Flag from table 
where (Age_Flag <> "AB" or Age_Flag IS NULL) and Date="2022-17-01";
```

Comment: I didnt see Null values when am runing this query

Comment: have you checked either if the date has NULL values or any NULL values

Comment: Yes it was there